# How do I find a replacement clutch and brake assembly for my chainsaw?

Tags: clutch, small-engine, chainsaw

I don't know anything about technical specifications for chainsaw clutches.
I'm not asking for shopping advice, but I don't know *how* to determine which parts are compatible.

Last year I bought an obscure aftermarket chainsaw from Amazon.
I chose this model because it has excellent ratings and reviews, and was super cheap ($150).
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08K3D9B7W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08K3D9B7W)

***PHOTOS OF MY CHAINSAW CLUTCH BELOW***

The chainsaw is no longer available for purchase, since the weird aftermarket brand appears to have disappeared ... (bankrupt?)
So naturally, I'm having a little difficulty finding parts for it.

I've been using it a lot, cutting down hundreds of small trees and dozens of large ones.
(My property is a forest, which I am clearing for pasture.)

For the money, this chainsaw is incredible - the motor is very powerful and effective, and I've had no problems with it.
However, the standard chrome chain got dull pretty quick, so I bought a replacement bar and a larger titanium chain for it, which made the chainsaw even better.
I made sure the new bar had the exact same mounting shape as the stock bar - and it fits the larger teeth on the titanium chain - still 20" length so I'm not overworking the engine.

Anyway, to make the new titanium chain work properly, my local small-engine mechanic recommended that I upgrade to a slightly larger sprocket, to fit the larger teeth.
I had no objection to this, so I let him install a new sprocket for me.

After this, the new chain worked flawlessly.
However, I noticed my local mechanic was very rough on my clutch, when removing it - he banged on it with a screwdriver and a large hammer, with full swings.
I noticed the top piece of my clutch, where he was banging (the piece you turn to unscrew, to remove the clutch) had a visible crack in the metal, where he had been banging it with the screwdriver.

I had many trees to cut down, so I ignored the crack and just got to work.
But about an hour later, that piece of my clutch broke off and blasted a hole through the brake assembly.

***(The chainsaw still works fine, even with the broken clutch. I cut down several more trees with the broken clutch, before I even realized there was a problem. And the brake still works perfectly too, it just has a hole in the plastic cover.

But it's probably not safe to keep using it like this, I imagine.)***

Of course now my local mechanic is "too busy" to do the research, to find a compatible new clutch for me, so I have to find one on my own.
But I have never shopped for a chainsaw clutch or brake assembly before, and I have no idea what I'm looking at (e.g. tech specs).

**How can I find a new chainsaw clutch and brake assembly with compatible specifications?

(A higher-performance upgrade, if possible?)**

*P.S. If you need me to remove the clutch and take photos of the disassembled parts, I can try to take it apart - but I've never taken a chainsaw apart before, so I'll have to watch some quick YouTube instruction videos and take it slowly.*

And yes I know my chainsaw is dirty. :D
I've been using it a lot, and I haven't cleaned it since it broke.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @GdD - I would disagree. The gist of the question is not shopping, but rather how would the OP go about finding a replacement clutch for the saw. If that is correct, I'd highly suggest the OP modify the question to specify this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about motor vehicle maintenance, although it is semi-related. Just not the right forum for it.

Comment: @Bevan small motor repairs have generally been accepted as on-topic for some time now, which is why we have a [tag:small-engine] tag... also gotta mention that [this isn't a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/333472) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the clutch for this is very generic. There's two main factors which are listed for the clutch in the adverts I see. One is the size of the center bore. The second is the pitch for the chain. If you do a Google search for "PINKWAY Chainsaw Clutch" you'll see a plethora of options come up from Amazon listings. Manufacturers such as QHALEN, Adefol, and SPERTECK pop up. I'll bet you they are all made by the same place, but just have different names on them. Your best bet is to remove the clutch and completely disassemble it to ensure you're getting the right clutch. The clutches shown on Amazon are in the exploded view, so you get a pretty good idea of what you're getting. Secondly, when you get the new clutch, measure it against the original to ensure fitment. If it's not the right one, send it back ... Amazon is really good about returns.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. After searching Amazon like you said, and reading reviews for the QHALEN clutch (which looks identical, visually), it looks like I have a generic Chinese-made chainsaw (hence the cheap price, I suppose). And it seems that all the Chinese chainsaws are the same saw with different obscure brand names, and they all use the same Chinese parts. So I think I can safely gamble on the clutch that _looks_ the same on Amazon. And like you said, returns are easy. Thanks again!